# ExtJS 6 Remove focused elements outline

Tags: extjs, extjs6

How I can remove focused elements (tab, grid cells, etc.) outline in my ExtJS 6 app? Is there any global config for this?

Example:

[image]

I managed to remove outline for tabs, buttons and grid cells with this CSS rules

```
* {
  outline: none !important;
}

.x-grid-item-focused .x-grid-cell-inner:before {
  border: 0;
}
```

but unfortunatly for some focused elements it doesnt work. I noticed that for some components ExtJS add different CSS rules to add border / outlines.

For example to border layour split separator component added `:after` with outlines.

Is there any complex solution for this issue?

*P.S. Why on Earth Sencha add this styles to framework without ability to remove it. IMO it's pretty annoying and complicates theming.*

Comment: you dont have to try it in css you can try   headerBorders: false,
 rowLines: false,

Comment: add these to your grid config maybe thats what you looking for

Comment: @salman-hassan-okz Nope, its not. It seems like outline issue, not border.

Comment: you can make it easy by uploading an image so people can check what you want ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had kinda same problem And i found this good blog about row-cell
here is the [Blog](https://www.sencha.com/blog/top-support-tips-september-2014/)
And here is the example [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/9dq&view/editor)

> here is the css code which remove grid focused row-cell border

```
.x-grid-item-focused .x-grid-cell-inner:before {
border: 0;
```

}

Comment: Yup, its like first link in Google. It solves issue with grid cells, but for other elements (border layout split panel for example) ExtjS add other rules (:after with outline). And I believe its not all cases. Im looking for complex solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you need but you could set these variables in var/all.scss or packages/local/own-theme/classic/sass/var/view/Table.scss

```
$grid-row-cell-focus-border-color: transparent;
$grid-row-cell-focus-border-width: 0;
```